# Calling a method of a subclass instance in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, inheritance, subclass

I'm starting to work with inheritance in C++ but I can't figure out how to call a method from a subclass if that subclass is in an array of elements of its superclass. When I try to call the subclass method, it just calls the superclass method.

This is the code I have in main.cpp:

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "shape.h"
#include "rectangle.h"

SDL_Surface * screen;
bool running = true;

rectangle Rectangle;
shape * Shapes[] = { &Rectangle };    // The array Shapes is initialized containing Rectangle

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE);
    while (running) {
        // Rectangle.draw(screen);    This calls the rectangle draw method fine
        Shapes[0]->draw(screen);   // This calls the shape draw method instead
    }

    return 0;
}
```

shape and rectangle are the two classes I'm working with; rectangle is a subclass of shape. Both shape and rectangle have a `draw()` function. The draw method in shape is empty, so nothing happens when it is called. The draw method in rectangle contains only `SDL_Quit()`, so if it is called the `SDL_Surface` screen will close out. But when I call `Shapes[0]->draw(screen)`, it calls the draw method in the shapes class instead of in the rectangle class, even though `Shapes[0]` is an instance of a rectangle. When I call `draw()` on the Rectangle object, it calls the `draw()` method from rectangle. Why is this?

Comment: Please show us the definitions of both classes. I'm guessing either both methods are not virtual, or their signatures differ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare any function that can be overridden by subclasses as `virtual`.

```
class Shapes {
  // Some implementation information...
  virtual void draw(SDL_Surface *screen);
};

class Rectangle : public Shapes {
  // This method will override the Shapes version.
  // You do not have to declare it virtual, IIRC, but it's advisable.
  virtual void draw(SDL_Surface *screen);
};
```